# Use destinationDir in gradle custom plugin

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle task where I create a sourceZip of my project and as a result a zip file Is created. I want that zip to be created in a specific folder source. In the task, I write it as

```
destinationDir = file('/source')
```

I cant use this directly in custom plugin as it gives error 'Gradle DSL method not found/; file()'
Is there any way we can use this in custom plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing `destinationDir = file('source')`

Answer (score 5):

The destinationDir property has been deprecated.
This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0.
Please use the destinationDirectory property instead.

see. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile:destinationDir